# Plugins inside Android Studio Marketplace not showing when browsing

Tags: android-studio, flutter, plugins

Android studio marketplace is not showing any plugins while I am browsing. I am trying to install the flutter plugin. The marketplace gets stuck on the loading spinner and when trying to search any plugin, it returns `nothing to show`. I uninstalled and re-installed Android Studio and still no success. I have internet connection and can access the plugin page for Android Studio in the browser. I am also up to date with the current version of Android Studio: v3.5.3.

I also tried to auto detect proxy settings and set the Automatic proxy configuration URL to `https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio` with no luck.

[image]

Comment: what plugin are you looking for?

Comment: i am looking for the flutter plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this problem rarely occures. you can search the plugin name from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/) and download it manually then install it in android studio.

go to `settings > plugins` click on settings icon in the tabbar then choose `install plugin from disk`. this is the onlyway to install the plugin if you cannot find it on the market

Answer (score 38):

You have to configure the plugin repository.

Go to the configuration setup at: File -> Settings -> Plugins. Click on the cog at the right of `installed`.
Then select `Manage Plugin Repositories` and add the following URL: `https://plugins.jetbrains.com/`

After a few seconds you should see the Marketplace plugins populate correctly.[image]

Comment: Great, but why doesn't android studio do that automatically?

Comment: I always get a read exclamation mark icon with the message `Connection failed` when I add this URL (Android Studio version 4.1.3).

Answer (score 6):

Please go to `Settings` > `Appearance and behaviour` >> `System Settings` >> `Http Proxy` and check `Auto-detect proxy settings`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try to uncheck File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System settings -> Updates -> Use secure connection. It would make the connection faster.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a permission problem. When I ran android studio as administrator then everything worked.